# Lock Shape text in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to lock shape and its text with VBA but no success.

I tried the following

```
    Shape.locked = True
    Shape.Text.locked = True

Selection.Locked = True 'working
Selection.Characters.Text.Locked = True  'not working
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is the `Shape` you are trying to lock?

Comment: The `Text` property has no `.Locked` property. • Also note that *"not working"* is a pretty useless error description. What is your actual goal? What do you want to achieve? If you want thes shapes not to be able to edit by anyone then you must protect your worksheet.

Comment: @Samuel Everson i am trying to lock rectangle shape and text inside it.

Comment: But as you show `Shape` is a variable that is not declared and empty (`Nothing`) as you didn't show how it was declared or set.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ but there are options in shape formatting panel to lock text and shape separately..

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection Did you try the macro recorder? So you would get a first idea of the code. Guessing code syntax will not result in a success.

Comment: The problem we have is we don't know what `Shape` is. Without knowing what object it is referencing we don't know what methods or properties it has.

Comment: I have attached image.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i tried macro recorder but for text part, there is no code generated only for shape lock its generated.

Comment: @Samuel Everson its rectangle shape as I said in the above comments. but all shapes have the same properties for locking shape and text separately.

Comment: If the macro recorder doesn't come up with code, there is probably no VBA code to do that.

Comment: As an example, `Sheet1.Shapes(1).Locked = True` will lock the first shape in the shapes collection. You'll need to work out the index number for your shapes - Note I tested this with a `TextBox` on `Sheet1`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ But we can manually lock text then why macro code is not generated?

Comment: @Samuel Everson As you said in you last comment, even I can lock shape with Selection.Locked = True but the main thing here is I want to lock text and I need control over text part.

Comment: I request any of you, who did down vote this question to revert it back. thanks

Comment: From a quick google of the [Shape object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape) you can see each property and method etc. From hovering over the `i` bubble next to the `Locked` checkbox, it states `Locking objects has no effect unless the sheet is protected.` You'll need to look at protecting your sheet to have locking your shapes (incliuding text) take effect.

Comment: Note that not for everything in Excel there is a VBA equivalent code. So it might be possible to do something in the user interface but you are not able to do the same in VBA. Especially when it comes to embedded objects like shapes, VBA  is not complete. • You probably got a down vote as there is no proper question according [ask]. And "not working" is not an error description that is useful to help you. If you get errors tell us exactly which error and in which line.

Comment: @Samuel Everson maybe you have not understood this feature so closely. but i want to tell that if we have lock shape checkbox checked, lock text unchecked then in sheet protection mode you can edit text even thought edit object is unchecked.

Comment: If you add a shape then text is automatically locked unless you push that checkbox. I don't know of any VBA code to trigger this box nor is something about that in the documentation, nor does macro recorder give a result. •  Conlusion: It (very likely) does not exist a VBA code to do that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i will take care with future questions..but this is the first time I got negative.

Comment: Don't worry about a down-vote, it is just one persons opinion. You can still improve the question by [edit]ing it to get up-votes.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for the confirmation on limitations. but I afraid to find any workaround to my program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212070/discussion-between-heavyload-collection-and-p).

Comment: Here is final working line Selection.LockedText = True

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the `lockedText` property of a `Shape`, you can use the (hidden) property object `DrawingObject`. Assuming your variable `shape` is set to the Shape object of your choice, try

```
shape.DrawingObject.LockedText = true
```

You can use `DrawingObject` also to set the `locked`-property, it seems that `shape.Locked` and `shape.DrawingObject.Locked` refer to the same value.

Unfortunately, `DrawingObject` is not documented, so it is not guaranteed that Microsoft will support this functionality in all (future) Excel releases.

Comment: i tried Selection.DrawingObject.LockedText = True but it comes with error. object doesn't support this method or property

Comment: You shouldn't work with `Selection`, selection could be everything. Use a variable of Type `Shape` and set it to the shape you want to modify. And please don't write *"comes with error"*, write exactly what you error is.

Comment: i got final line of code and its working to lock text Selection.LockedText = True

Comment: I've just tested with `Sheet1.Shapes(2).DrawingObject.LockedText = True` which worked fine - in this test `Shapes(2)` is a rectangle i've put on `Sheet1` which is the 2nd shape on that sheet.

Comment: @Samuel Everson  yes it's working ".LockedText" is the property we didn't know. it's hard to find documentation on these.

Comment: @FunThomas Nice to know. Another one in my list of "vba code that actually exists but doesn't get recorded".